# OpenOffice-Calc advanced filter

Tags: macos, openoffice-calc

In OpenOffice-Calc, using the advanced filter, how can I compare one column to another?

As an example, I need to filter for items that have less than a 30 days supply. Using the column name `Test`, my criteria are below.

```
Test  
=(BOH<=Thirty)
```

I have column headers of `BOH` (Bottles on Hand), `Thirty` (how many bottles are sold in 30 days) and a new column `Test`. I get the following error.

> Range does not contain valid query.

Why is the formula returning this error message?

Comment: What version of Open Office are you using?

Comment: OO 3.4.1, Mac OS 10.8.3

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that you can reference columns by their name the way that you are in your question.

You need to reference individual cells by column(A-Z...) followed by row(1-100...). Take the following example:

[image]

The formula ends up being the following:

- =A2<=B2
- =A3<=B3
- =A4<=B4

And so on...

I did this with [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/), but you should get the same behavior out of OpenOffice.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to do that (create a new column for the test and set the test equal to true) using names. Unfortunately, I need to test for several other conditions as well. Using that method I actually need to create columns _in the spreadsheet_.  What I was hoping to do was set the tests _in the criteria_, and that isn't working. I shouldn't have to have a full spreadsheet column for a test on data already in the spreadsheet.

Comment: @PaulBressler Can you add those conditions to your question?